# Tile a texture to a rectangle from the top

Tags: c#, .net, xna, textures, farseer

I'm trying to tile a texture to a rectangle in a certain way. For example, here is my texture:

[image]

Currently, it tiles it to my rectangle such that the texture gets cut off at the top of the rectangle:

[image]

I want to tile my texture such that it gets cut off at the bottom of my rectangle:

[image]

I use the following logic to create and draw a rectangle in my game and tile it:

```
public class HoopsGame : Game
{

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Body _ground;
    Texture2D _groundTexture;
    World _world;

    public HoopsGame()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        _world = new World(new Vector2(0f, 9.8f));
        int groundHeight = (int)(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.05);
        Rectangle groundRectangle = new Rectangle(0, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - groundHeight, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, groundHeight);
        _ground = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(_world, groundRectangle.Width, groundRectangle.Height, 0f, groundRectangle);

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        _groundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("court");
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        Content.Unload();
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Opaque, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone);
        spriteBatch.Draw(_groundTexture, new Vector2(0, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - ((Rectangle)_ground.UserData).Height), (Rectangle)_ground.UserData, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't make it extremely clear, but I assume your brick texture is _groundTexture in the code. I really don't have a lot of experience with microsoft XNA, but since it's a tileable texture, have you considered getting the dimensions of your rectangle, then the dimensions of the tileable texture, then doing an operation like:

```
//this is of course pseudocode

offset_y = Rectangle_Y_Coordinate % Texture_Y_Coordinate
```

This modular operation will give you the amount of the texture that will get cut off. For example, if your rectangle has a height of 20 and your texture has a height of 7, you will be left with your texture being mapped a 3rd time but only up to a height of 6 because 20 % 7 = 6.

Then when you map the texture to your rectangle just subtract that y offset when you give it your y coordinate and you should get the desired result. Please let me know if I was a bit unclear. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Offsetting would be great but I'm not sure how to apply a texture offset in XNA.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too proficient in XNA, but when you write:
  
spriteBatch.Draw(_groundTexture, new Vector2(0, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - ((Rectangle)_ground.UserData).Height), (Rectangle)_ground.UserData, Color.White);  
  
aren't you allocating a texture to your rectangle in the form  
  
SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture2D, RectangleCoordinates, Color).  
  
I then assumed you could do something like:  
  
SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture2D,(Rectangle_x,Rectangle_y - y_offset),Color)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything for that, unfortunately. The `Vector2` just translates. There is only a `Draw(Texture2D texture, Rectangle destinationRectangle, Rectangle? sourceRectangle, Color color)` method that might be able to do something similar, but its still useless. The sourceRectangle is first drawn and then scaled to the destinationRectangle. So I would need to make sure that the source rectangle fits my `Texture2D` evenly and then draw to that, but the problem is I can't find a way to offset a texture thus far. It seems like more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Seems to work if I modify the source Rectangle. I got it and I'll post the full code solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

What worked in the end was using a different `Draw` method, specifically `Draw(Texture2D texture, Rectangle destinationRectangle, Rectangle? sourceRectangle, Color color)`, and offsetting the source `Rectangle`'s Y coordinate as Orren mentioned:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Opaque, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone);
Rectangle source = (Rectangle)_ground.UserData;
if (source.Height > _groundTexture.Height)
    source.Y += source.Height - _groundTexture.Height;
if (_groundTexture.Height > source.Height)
    source.Y -= _groundTexture.Height - source.Height;
Rectangle destination = new Rectangle(0, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - ((Rectangle)_ground.UserData).Height, source.Width, source.Height);
spriteBatch.Draw(_groundTexture, destination, source, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```